# Looping through elements of a list using a purrr-like function

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to loop through elements of a list containing NULL object using a purrr-like function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I would like to do it using the `map` family to achieve this if possible

```r
library(reprex)
library(purrr)
library(glue)
# hi, I am trying to find a way to replace the element of a list
#Data set-up

#my list
mylist=list(
  a=1,
  b=NULL,
  c=NULL,
  d=0,
  e=NULL)

# the data to repalce
ax = c(1,2,3)
bx = c(1,4,5)
cx = c(1,6,7)
dx = c(1,8,9)
ex = c(10,2,9)

#the long way
if(is.null(mylist$a)){
  mylist$a = ax
}

if(is.null(mylist$b)){
  mylist$b = bx
}

if(is.null(mylist$c)){
  mylist$c = cx
}

if(is.null(mylist$d)){
  mylist$d = dx
}

if(is.null(mylist$e)){
  mylist$e = ex
}

mylist #this what I want
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1 4 5
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 1 6 7
#> 
#> $d
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $e
#> [1] 10  2  9

#want to create a function to change the element of a list
#and loop through all of the elements using a purrr-like function

null_funct <- function(mylist_var=mylist, var){
  if(is.null(mylist_var[[var]])){
    mylist_var[var]= glue("{var}x")
  }
  
}
list_to_loop <- c("a","b", "c", "d","e")
map(list_to_loop, null_funct, mylist_var=mylist)
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> NULL
#It does not give me the expected results
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want. What makes it easier to do is to make the replacement data into a named list that uses the same names as mylist. Instead of mapping over list elements, you can map over names and then grab the replacement from the replacement list when needed. Flattening and setting names at the end cleans it up.

```r
library(purrr)

#my list
mylist=list(
  a=1,
  b=NULL,
  c=NULL,
  d=0,
  e=NULL)

# the data to repalce
ax = c(1,2,3)
bx = c(1,4,5)
cx = c(1,6,7)
dx = c(1,8,9)
ex = c(10,2,9)

#Here's my solution:
list_names <- names(mylist)
replace_list = list(ax, bx, cx, dx, ed) %>% set_names(list_names)
map(list_names, ~ ifelse(is.null(mylist[[.x]]), replace_list[.x], mylist[[.x]])) %>% 
  flatten %>% 
  set_names(list_names)
```